# Como imprimir datos de tipo clase?

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos, clase, método

En el metodo `queueAnalysis`, cuando mando a imprimir  `System.out.println("Original: " + queue + "\n");`,  `System.out.println("colados: " + names + "\n");` y 
        `System.out.println("Cola final: " +queue);`, me da como output `direcciones de memoria`, `null` y `direcciones de memoria`, ya intente aplicar un `iterator` y aplique un casting de tipo de la clase `Customer` pero aun asi sigue dando direcciones de memoria como salida. Por que?,

**Como puedo solucionar el problema?**

```
class Customer {

String name;
int ticket;

Customer(String name, int ticket) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ticket = ticket;

}

String getName() {
    return name;

}

int getTicket() {
    return ticket;
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Customer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.add(new Customer("a1", 1));
    queue.add(new Customer("a2", 2));
    queue.add(new Customer("a3", -1));
    queue.add(new Customer("a4", -1));

    queueAnalysis(queue);
}

public static void queueAnalysis(Queue<Customer> queue) {

    System.out.println("Original: " + queue + "\n");
    String names[] = null;
    int cant = 0;
    int tam = queue.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        if (queue.peek().getTicket() == -1) {
            names[i] = queue.peek().getName();
            cant++;
            queue.poll();


        }

    }
    System.out.println("colados: " + names + "\n");
    System.out.println("Cola final: " +queue); 

    //Customer c;
    for (Iterator it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println((Customer) it.next());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Y qué es lo qué quieres mostrar?

Comment: En original, toda la cola completa, asi como llego, asi tiene que imprimirse. En colados, las cadenas a3 y a4. Y en Cola final,  las cadenas a1 y a2. @Edu3D

Comment: Estoy escribiendo la respuesta, dame un segundo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicional a la respuesta dada por @Edu3D, debes cambiar la forma de como obtener los datos de los colados y la `fila` final, esto a que no estas accediendo la cola por indices y cuando haces `peek()` o `poll()` siempre es sobre sobre el objeto que esta en el `head` de la fila, aca modifico el método

```
public static void queueAnalysis(Queue<Customer> queue) {
  System.out.println("Original: " + queue + "\n");
  Queue<Customer> colados = new LinkedList<>();
  Queue<Customer> noColados = new LinkedList<>();
  while(!queue.isEmpty()){
    if (queue.peek().getTicket() == -1) {
      colados.add(queue.poll());
    }else{
      noColados.add(queue.poll());
    }
  }
  System.out.println("colados: " + colados + "\n");
  System.out.println("Cola final: " + noColados);
  //Customer c;
  for (Iterator it = queue.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    System.out.println((Customer) it.next());
  }
}
```

Esto solo funciona si haces los cambios mencionados por @Edu3D de sobreescribir el método `toString()` de la clase `Customer`

```
public class Customer {
  String name;
  int ticket;

  public Customer(String name, int ticket) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ticket = ticket;
  }
  String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  int getTicket() {
    return ticket;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return getName()+ "-" + getTicket();        
  }
}
```

Comment: Añade a la respuestas los cambios de la clase así estará todo en una respuesta. Buen aporte

Answer (score 2):

No puedes imprimir un arrayList directamente o un vector:

```
for( Customer c: queue ){
  System.out.println( "Original: " + c.getName( ) + "" + c.getTicket( ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar el nombre de los objetos o algo más simplemente sobrescribe el método **ToString()** de la clase **Customer**

```
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int ticket;

    public Customer(String name, int ticket) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ticket = ticket;

    }

    String getName() {
        return name;

    }

    int getTicket() {
        return ticket;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getName()+ "-" + getTicket();        
    }
}
```